# Remap keys only for a particular application/program/process

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Sometimes it is convenient to have <kbd>Escape</kbd> where <kbd>Tab</kbd> usually is and arrows where <kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd> usually are. Sometimes applications are not very configurable in terms of keybindings. There is xmodmap which allows remapping system-wide. But is is possible to remap only for particular application/program/process?

Comment: Not directly. But the window manager can change key mappings when the window focus changes. Not all window managers support that. What window manager or desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Ubuntu Gnome, but if something better and more flexible exists, it  would be pleasure to migrate

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://medium.com/@canadaduane/key-remapping-in-linux-2021-edition-47320999d2aa) does a great job breaking down the options for you. The diagram copied below summarizes things even more succinctly.
[image]

Perhaps one of two tools matching your request (autokey & xkeysnail) will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're still using X11, AutoKey will do all but the Tab key. Each action (phrase or script) has an optional associated window filter. If that matches your active window then the action is performed. Otherwise it behaves as if AutoKey was not there. The tab key won't work as a hotkey unless you xmodmap (etc.) it to something else first. Then, it *might* work.

If you can define mutually exclusive window filters for two different application windows, then you can even reuse the same hotkeys(shortcuts) to perform different actions in each of the windows.

Defining window filters involves a few wrinkles, so if you go that route and run into difficulties, come over to [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey) and we can get it sorted.